# Is this data frame structure possible in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to make a specific form of data frame using Pandas and numpy.

Like this :

[image]

I just know possibility of making this.

I searched a lot of information of multi-index, but it doesn't say that a different number of columns.

Comment: No, you can have multiple layers of nesting, but columns go at the top. You can just leave column 3 empty for those rows where it's not used. I suggest looking at [wide vs. long](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_and_narrow_data) data.

Comment: show a sample dataset source (e.g. csv file) we can do it using pure python (without any third party libraries like pandas)........ you can choose to import it into pandas later on if you wish.

Comment: @Joshua I have lists. it has many of datas. for example list 1 = [a,[1,2,1,2,1,2],b,[3,4,3,4,3,4] ... so on ] and list 2 = [a,[[1,2,1,2,1,2],[3,4,3,4,3,4],[5,6,5,6,5,6]],b ... so on]

Comment: @Swier Thanks. I will seperate 2 columns / 3 columns dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems not to be possible with (standalone) pandas. As mentioned in comments, columns can not be changed within a DataFrame.

You might create two DataFrames (one for type 1 and another for type 2). You can create a dict containing theses DataFrames:

```py
data = {
    'type1': pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'column#1', 'column#2', 'column#3']
    'type2': pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'column#1', 'column#2']
}
```

Alternatively, you create a DataFrame with columns A and B, instead of column C you can create five columns (Column_1_1, Column_1_2, Column_1_3, Column_2_1, Column_2_2). If you want to store a row of type 1, you can leave columns 2_1 and 2_2 empty, if you need to store data of type 2, you can leave columns 1_1, 1_2 and 1_3 empty.

The latter approach would make your column B (type) redundant, because you'd be able to determine the data type based on filled and empty columns.

If all rows have the same value in column A, you can use [DataFrame Attributes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.attrs.html) instead of creating a column.